# Shortcuts for "Overview" and "Scan" buttons in Image Capture

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, image-capture

I was manually scanning a couple of documents. It's tedious work, partly because it's manual, and party because I needed to make an overview scan first and then the actual scan in Image Capture.

This got me to think, are there any shortcuts for the "Overview" and "Scan" options in Image Capture? Most of Apple's native apps have shortcuts for the most common actions, and I would expect some shortcut for scanning to be set to Command+S or Command+R, or something similar.

I tried looking for a menu bar item which allowed me to overview or scan (which I then would be able to assign to a shortcut in the keyboard preferences), but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Many printers have a document feeder function. That would allow you to scan all the documents at once. Does yours have that feature?

Comment: Yes but the documents I'm scanning are unfortunately booklets

Comment: Well that's sucks :) May I ask what the benefit would be to doing this? I don't think the time difference between pressing a keyboard shortcut is much different then just clicking the buttons, escpailly because overview takes so long.

Comment: I think the main issue is with having to move the mouse and do the extra work, when you don’t need to :) pretty much why we have all of those other shortcuts in pages or finder that we don’t use that often, but still warrant one

Comment: Would an AppleScript work?

Comment: Yes, definitely! I’m hoping that I can figure it out and post it as an answer to this question.